# Visual Studio 2015 bug? Inserting spaces instead of tabs for XAML text editor

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2015

I have my Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> XAML -> Tabs set to "Keep Tabs" instead of spaces. However, when I auto-indent my code using the shortcut `Ctrl-E-D`, it inserts spaces everywhere in my XAML code.

I did not have this issue in VS 2013.

[image: XAML]

I have tried setting tabs for XML, HTML even for All Languages and it still inserts spaces in my XAML files.

[image: All]

Is this a bug or do the text editor setting for XAML reside somewhere else?

Comment: Eh, I quit worrying about those details long ago and instead just use the XAML Styler extension with some custom config to "beautify" it all on save anyway. Not an answer, just a suggestion.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the suggestion, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fixed in Visual Studio Tools for Universal Windows Apps v1.1: see the [release notes](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e9df01f6-1474-4a4e-98fc-2567591c764f/update-11-release-notes-and-installation-instructions?forum=Win10SDKToolsIssues).

Even though it's for Universal Windows Apps, the XAML editor fix seems to also apply to WPF.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was quite vexing. I finally figured out that it has to do with the "Smart Indent" setting. With this setting selected (as it is for you, according to the screenshot of your xaml settings) Visual Studio will indent all new lines to align with the first attribute in the line above. So if that previous attribute is not at a natural tab-stop, VS will pad the new line's indentation with spaces.

I only know of three options to resolve this:

1. Change the Indenting to `Block` instead of `Smart`.
2. Use a tab (rather than a space) in the previous line to separate the first attribute from it's element tag. This will sometimes introduce up to 3 extra characters of white-space gaps in your xaml (unfortunately), but it will ensure the first attribute is aligned with a tab stop, negating the need to add spaces in the lines below.
3. Don't include any attributes on the first line of the element tag. (I.e., put them all on separate lines.)